# Generate a simple counterexample

Tags: polynomials, roots, examples-counterexamples, conditional-expectation, cubics

I want to construct a density function $f$ with support $[0,1]$, such that there exists some $q \in (0,1]$ for which the following equation has *more than one* solutions for $x \in [0,1]$:

$$
x=(1-q)\mathbb{E}(X)+q\mathbb{E}(X|X \leq x)
$$

This boils down to:

$$
x=(1-q)\mathbb{E}(X)+q\frac{\int\limits^x_0sf(s)ds}{F(x)}
$$

I have tried for several days with various polynomial functions upto cubic but I'm not able to generate such an example. Any help is most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, cubic functions are too smooth for your purpose.

Try $q={1\over2}$ and a uniform distribution over the intervals $[0.00;0.01]\cup[0.30;0.31]\cup[0.69;0.70]\cup[0.99;1.00]$. Then of course $\mathbb E(X)=\frac12$ and ...
[image: LHS=RHS]
... you can see three intersections.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is most useful. I have posted a related question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4286795/generate-counterexample-related-to-conditional-expectations

Pls have a look if you can. I have been trying both problems for quite some time now. Thanks so much once again.